# Export fields with multiple nested values from JSON to CSV

Tags: json, powershell, nested, nested-loops

I need to import some JSON data am getting into my database. I'd like to use PowerShell and figured out a little, but I need help getting the final piece together.

Here is my existing PowerShell script.

```
Get-Content -Path "t:\1.json"  | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select-Object -expand data | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Set-Content "t:\1.csv"
```

It does everything but doesnot get the badges details out in single cav along with user name. My question is, how can I get all details in single csv?

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Shiva",
         "email": "Shiva@example.com",
         "organization": "Team",
         "badges": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "AWS Certified Developer",
                  "id": "001"
               }
            ]
         },
         "id": "1001"
      },
      {
         "name": "Rudra",
         "email": "Rudra@example.com",
         "organization": "Team",
         "badges": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Certified Google Associate Cloud Engineer",
                  "id": "006"
               }
            ]
         },
         "id": "1002"
      },
      {
         "name": "Alazar",
         "email": "Alazar@example.com",
         "organization": "Team",
         "badges": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Google Cloud Data Engineer Certified",
                  "id": "007"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Google Certified Professional Cloud Network Engineer",
                  "id": "008"
               },
               {
                  "name": "AWS Solution Architect",
                  "id": "009"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Certified Google Associate Cloud Engineer",
                  "id": "006"
               }
            ]
         },
         "id": "1003"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031293/powershell-flattening-nested-json-and-convert-it-to-csv

Comment: Or have a look at: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ConvertTo-FlatObject-396a6e0a

Answer (score 1):

You need to add new rows of data for each badge a person can have.

Something like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path 't:\1.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).data | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($badge in $_.badges.data) {
        $_ | Select-Object *,
                @{Name = 'badge_id';   Expression = { $badge.id }},
                @{Name = 'badge_name'; Expression = { $badge.name }} -ExcludeProperty badges
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 't:\1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

After this, file 't:\1.csv' will look like this:

```
"name","email","organization","id","badge_id","badge_name"
"Shiva","Shiva@example.com","Team","1001","001","AWS Certified Developer"
"Rudra","Rudra@example.com","Team","1002","006","Certified Google Associate Cloud Engineer"
"Alazar","Alazar@example.com","Team","1003","007","Google Cloud Data Engineer Certified"
"Alazar","Alazar@example.com","Team","1003","008","Google Certified Professional Cloud Network Engineer"
"Alazar","Alazar@example.com","Team","1003","009","AWS Solution Architect"
"Alazar","Alazar@example.com","Team","1003","006","Certified Google Associate Cloud Engineer"
```